# For loop not appearing to execute

Tags: java, for-loop

I've seen this asked on here before, but my problem doesn't seem to be solved by any of the other answers.

Code:

```
public static int parseInt(char[] array) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
        int r = array[n];
        total = total + r;  
    }   
    return total;
}
```

I'm just not seeing the error. Please help.

Comment: What is the size of input array??

Comment: Should probably add - am trying to pass this:

char[] array = {1,2,3};
System.out.print(MyInteger.parseInt(array));

Comment: How do you know that it's not executed? Are you debugging?

Comment: I ran the code - total prints as zero (initial value), expected output with input array {1,2,3} is 6.

Comment: Add a print inside the for loop to check the value of `r` (and that it's actually looping)

Comment: Can you modify your question to include your `Main`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this method? Do you have to pass `char[]` as input? Shouldn't there be `int[]` instead?

Comment: @Pshemo he has another problem than that. This code should run and return 6 if passed `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Main is pretty long - this is the sole remaining part of a homework problem set. I added a print value, it never loops.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Proof: http://ideone.com/gDMjQD  Can you show us how do you call the parseInt method?

Comment: Put the print outside the loop to print the length of the array and check that the method is called at all.

Comment: @mostruash It does if it is used correctly: http://ideone.com/eMrFP2

Comment: I am really sorry. I have no clue what happened between the last time I ran the code and now, but it is running properly. I swear I ran it a few dozen times before posting here, checked everything possible and it still didn't work. It is now. Sorry to have wasted your time and thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Cory Somehow the array you pass to the method is either empty or it is consisted of integers of value 0. Please debug your code, learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no error raised (in your case, say `NullPointerException`), **make sure your length of the param array is larger than 0**

You can easily use `System.out.println(array.length)`, or better, mark a breakpoint in your method and run in debug mode. You will solve all the similar problems by yourself.